# Disable screenshot of a pdf in React (web)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, screenshot, react-pdf

In our web application, we are using react-pdf to display different PDFs.

For one of the PDF, there is a requirement that we should not allow user to take screenshot. We are not using React-native.

Now I know that we cannot stop user from taking screenshot as it is not handled by browser, but can we show a black or white screen when the user views the screenshot.

Currently, I have disabled right click and save via print, but the screenshot part is tricky.

This is what happens in Netflix and Prime video, but I want to implement it for PDF.

If anyone has implemented or have any ideas about such functionality, please help.

Read about DRM as well but not sure how to implement it and if it will work for PDF

**Edit**
The purpose is not to edit pdf but to provide a black screen when user views the screenshot taken

Comment: @KJ no… this is not what I am looking for

Comment: @KJ I know about this tool but how can I use it. How to implement and integrate this in our react app